# Android: upgrade gradle 4.4 with httpcomponents - Error: Program type already present: org.apache.http.auth.ChallengeState

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When upgrading to Gradle 4.4 my app I faces the following errors during the build. How can I upgrade?

**I know (and proofed) it has to do with these libraries:**

```
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5') {
    exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
}
```

> Program type already present: org.apache.http.auth.ChallengeState
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:
>   org.apache.http.auth.ChallengeState, sources=[Unknown source file],
>   tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

My other apps use other ways to integrate over http. The cost/benefit of this app is lower, so I would like to keep the httpclient integration.

Further errors are:

> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException:
>   Compilation failed to complete    at
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:76)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
>     at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:67)  at
>   com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:107)

My dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5') {
        exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
    }
    implementation files('libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/GraphView-3.1.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
```

...

In my build.gradle I have (of course) added:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy' <======
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the easiest but a better solution is migrating the http calls to OkHttp. When not doing now, you need to migrate in the near future.

The apps I migrated to OkHttp are working fine. OkHttp is nice to use.